# Looping through memory using Zero Page indirect addressing on the 6502

Tags: loops, 6502

I have written a small 6502 program to loop through memory and use STA Zero Page Indirect Addressing to store a value in 128 consecutive memory locations, but the program doesn't appear to be working. It should store 128 copies of the value $01 to memory address $0400 on-wards but it does not. What am I doing wrong?

```
        *=$8001

        ; set $00,$01 to $0400
        LDA #$00
        STA $00
        LDA #$04
        STA $01


        CLC             ; Clear carry and decimal mode
        CLD
        LDX #128        ; Loop 128 times
        LDY #0

loop    LDA #$01        ; the value to store
        STA ($00),Y     ; store A to the address held in $00,$01
        
                        ; Add 1 to $00,$01 (16-bit addition)

        LDA $00
        ADC #1
        STA $00
        LDA $01
        ADC #0
        STA $01
                        ; do it 127 more times
        DEX
        BNE loop
        RTS
```

Comment: Whether this works will depend on what address you start writing to. The given address is OK, but you should always CLC before your first ADC (unless you know C is already in the desired state). In the code above you are only doing CLC outside the loop, which is not correct. Other than that, offsetting is exactly what the index registers are for, as mentioned by larsks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're incrementing the value stored at `$00`, but shouldn't you be manipulating `Y` instead?   Something like:

```
        *=$8001

        LDA #<$0400      ; store $0400 into $00 and $01
        STA $00
        LDA #>$0400
        STA $01

        LDY #128      ; load 128 into Y
        LDA #$01      ; load 01 into A
loop    DEY
        STA ($00),Y   ; store A into $0400 + Y
        BNE loop      ; loop until Y is zero
        RTS
```

In this loop, we get rid of `X`, initialize `Y` to 128, and then decrement `Y` for each loop iteration. This means we're filling memory "backwards".

### Note  1

Addresses `$00` and `$01` are often special (e.g.,
on the C64 these addresses control processor features), so depending
on your environment you may need to choose different zero memory
locations.

### Note 2

If I were writing this, I would avoid hardcoding addresses directly into the code, and instead declare a named storage location. When testing your code locally, I assembled it using [64tass](http://tass64.sourceforge.net/) and the following code:

```
        *=$00fb
addr    .word ?     ; declare two bytes of storage at * and *+1
                    ; I'm using $00fb because this is an unused zero
                    ; page location on the c64 (and I'm testing using
                    ; the VICE emulator).

        *=$8001
        LDA #<$0400    ; store $0400 into addr and addr+1
        STA addr
        LDA #>$0400
        STA addr+1

        LDY #128
        LDA #$01
loop    DEY
        STA (addr),Y
        BNE loop
        RTS
```

---

## Update 1

Your original code seems to work just fine for me. Note that when testing in a C64 emulator, the range `$0400-$0480` corresponds to the screen memory (see e.g. [this memory map](http://sta.c64.org/cbm64mem.html)), so when returning to BASIC, that range is overwritten. For example, with your code loaded at `$8001`, I see the following code in the monitor (assuming we're storing the address in `$FB` and `$FC`):

```
(C:$e5cf) d 8001
.C:8001  A9 00       LDA #$00
.C:8003  85 FB       STA $FB
.C:8005  A9 04       LDA #$04
.C:8007  85 FC       STA $FC
.C:8009  18          CLC
.C:800a  D8          CLD
.C:800b  A2 80       LDX #$80
.C:800d  A0 00       LDY #$00
.C:800f  A9 01       LDA #$01
.C:8011  91 FB       STA ($FB),Y
.C:8013  A5 FB       LDA $FB
.C:8015  69 01       ADC #$01
.C:8017  85 FB       STA $FB
.C:8019  A5 FC       LDA $FC
.C:801b  69 00       ADC #$00
.C:801d  85 FC       STA $FC
.C:801f  CA          DEX
.C:8020  D0 ED       BNE $800F
.C:8022  60          RTS
```

If I place a breakpoint at `$8022` and tune the code...

```
(C:$8029) break 8022
BREAK: 1  C:$8022  (Stop on exec)
(C:$8029) g 8001
#1 (Stop on  exec 8022)  064 011
.C:8022  60          RTS            - A:04 X:00 Y:00 SP:f2 ..-...Z.    4131803
```

And then inspect the target memory range, it's filled with `$01`:

```
(C:$8022) m 400,480
>C:0400  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01   ................
>C:0410  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01   ................
>C:0420  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01   ................
>C:0430  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01   ................
>C:0440  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01   ................
>C:0450  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01   ................
>C:0460  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01   ................
>C:0470  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01   ................
>C:0480  20
```

But as soon as I return to BASIC, it looks like this:

```
(C:$e5d4) m 400,480
>C:0400  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20                   
>C:0410  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20                   
>C:0420  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  12 05 01 04  19 2e 20 20           ......  
>C:0430  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20                   
>C:0440  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20                   
>C:0450  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20                   
>C:0460  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20                   
>C:0470  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20                   
>C:0480  20
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should be inc'ing register Y to be more efficient, but the addition code I wrote should work. I found some unused zero page addresses at $FA to $FD and I have modified the code to use two of those, but it still doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I eventually went with your code and it works great.